# Google's compression proxy and missing X-Forwarded-For headers

Tags: android, google-chrome, proxy, http-headers

My understanding is that requests with a hostname that begins with google-proxy are requests from Google's compression proxies primarily used by mobile users.

According to the URL below Google will always relay the user's real IP in the X-Forwarded-For header, but we're seeing a good number of google-proxy requests with no such header.

Based on Google's published info at the URL below, does anyone know if we can we safely assume that any google-proxy request without an IP in an X-Forwarded-For header is some type of automated request from within Google, and not a real request from a real user?

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Answer (score 0):

I just published this [new doc about data compression proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression-for-isps) on behalf of the engineering team.

You should see a `Via` HTTP-Header on all requests issued by the proxy that looks like `Via: 1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy`. If this isn't on the request then it is from another service.  The infrastructure for the compression proxy in theory could be being used by any other Service inside Google.